# How to exclude some components from dynamic routing in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, routes, next.js13

I am building an app with Next.js 13.

I have components in my app folder.

In Next.js, the file system is used to define the routes by default. If you have a file like app/MenuItem/page.tsx, it automatically creates a route accessible at localhost:3000/MenuItem.

How can I prevent access to this route?

Is it possible without moving the component outside of the app folder?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, if you are working with components its recommended to avoid file name as page.tsx as it creates a route.**

**Good Approach:** You can rename the file anything except page.tsx e.g. index.tsx/regular-item.tsx anything it will work fine and will prevent to generate as a page. You can also rename the directory with underscore(_) like _MenuItem it will also work as preventive of a route.

**Another Approach:** by using middleware

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/MenuItem') {
        const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
        url.pathname = '/'; //or anything
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Read more about middleware at https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware